# Update progress bar message from custom code, depending upon last action executed

Tags: java, install4j

I am evaluating Install4j (version 7.0.8) and developed a tryout installer.

Installer consists of bunch of actions and after every action, progress bar is to be updated with a specific message.
Built in action is available to set progress bar message but it needs to be inserted before that every action for which progress bar is to be updated.

In this approach, code to update progress bar is distributed throughout installer actions.
Is it possible to have custom code which will update progress bar depending upon the last action executed ?

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Progress can be set via the API:

```
    context.getProgressInterface().setStatusMessage("Message");
```

`com.install4j.api.context.ProgressInterface` has other methods for setting messages, percentages and indeterminate state.

Comment: Thats true but how to determine in custom code which was the last action executed? Is it possible to get that action id somehow? I figured out one way to do by capturing event AFTER_EXECUTE_ACTION but not able to determine last action executed.

Comment: Currently that is not available. The event for `AFTER_EXECUTE_ACTION` is of type `InstallerActionEvent`, I've just added a method `getActionId()` to that class. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for you help.. Will do as per your suggestion.